# Geolocalização - retornando marco zero apenas no servidor

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocalização

Tenho o seguinte código que retorna a minha latitude e longitude.

***[Fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WEprVY)***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Geolocalização</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Geolocalização</h1>
</body>
<script src="j/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="j/gears_init.js"></script>
<script src="j/geo.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        if(geo_position_js.init()){
            geo_position_js.getCurrentPosition(geo_success, geo_error);
        }
    });

    function geo_success(p){
        alert("Encontrado na latitude "+p.coords.latitude+", longitude "+p.coords.longitude);
    }

    function geo_error(){
        alert("Não conseguimos encontrar você!");
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Upando este código em um arquivo na minha nuvem da AWS ou usando este fiddle dentro da rede corporativo da empresa, ele me devolve o marco zero da geolocalização (Praça da Sé - SP), seja pelo computador ou seja pelo celular acessando a internet da empresa.

Executando o mesmo teste pelo celular em uma rede 4G (localização ligada), acessando o código na AWS, ele também me retorna o marco zero, mas se eu acesso o fiddle codepen pelo celular em 4G, ele me retorna a minha localização atual perfeitamente!

Alguém já experienciou algo semelhante? Preciso de alguma liberação dentro do firewall da empresa? Liberar alguma coisa dentro da AWS? Algo que talvez defira a minha Cloud com os servidores do CodePen.

Comment: Passei por algo parecido na empresa e no nosso caso foi o _firewall_; tenta ver se não é o mesmo com você, já que usando o _4G_ ele mostra o ponto corretamente

Comment: @rLinhares se for realmente a questão do firewall, não tenho oq fazer, é deixar assim por questões de segurança, mas no caso da AWS o que pode ser?

Comment: A questão do _firewall_ era bom se você conseguisse fazer teste sem ele, pra garantir que é esse o ponto mesmo. Quanto _AWS_ não acredito que precise de alguma configuração extra.

Comment: @rLinhares é que o unico outro ambiente que consigo testar é na AWS, mas la algo está barrando

Comment: Entendi.. vamos esperar alguém tentar ajudar então :P